# What is the right way to compress and decompress UTF-8 data using zlib?

Tags: python, json, utf-8, compression, python-2.x

I have a very long JSON message that contains characters that go beyond the ASCII table. I convert it into a string as follows:

```
messStr = json.dumps(message,encoding='utf-8', ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True)
```

I need to store this string using a service that restricts its size to X bytes. I want to split the JSON string into pieces of length X and store them separately. I ran into some issues doing this (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364594/why-am-i-getting-no-json-object-could-be-decoded-when-batch-writing-items-into)) so I want to compress the string slices to work around those issues. I tried to do this:

```
ss = mStr[start:fin]    # get piece of length X
ssc = zlib.compress(ss) # compress it
```

When I do that, I get the following error from `zlib.compress`:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 225: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is the right way to compress a UTF-8 string and what is then the right way to decompress it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your JSON data is **not** UTF-8 encoded. The `encoding` parameter to the `json.dumps()` function instructs it how to interpret Python byte strings in `message` (e.g. the input), not how to encode the resulting *output*. It doesn't encode the output *at all* because you used `ensure_ascii=False`.

Encode the data before compression:

```
ssc = zlib.compress(ss.encode('utf8'))
```

When decompressing again, there is no need to decode from UTF-8; the `json.loads()` function assumes UTF-8 if the input is a bytestring.

Comment: Above only works in Python 3.x since zlib package (finally) takes byte-array as input note a string. In Python 2.7 this won't work because zlib.compress takes a string and uses ascii codec to turn the input into a byte-array - hence the OP's error message.

Comment: @Debriter yes, the problem in the question is unique to Python 2.

Answer (score 14):

A little addition to Martijn's response.
I read [in an Enthought blog](http://blog.enthought.com/general/compressing-text-using-pythons-unicode-support/#.VHBO7otJyqw) a nifty one liner statement that will spare you the need to import zlib in your own code.

Safely compressing a string (including your json dump) would look like that:

```
ssc = ss.encode('utf-8').encode('zlib_codec')
```

Decompressing back to utf-8 would be:

```
ss = ssc.decode('zlib_codec').decode('utf-8')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what worked for me, rather than the other answer. Thanks for the epic solution! +1

Comment: @nurettin this code worked on python2 at it was when the question was asked. From your error message, it seems like you are using python3.

Comment: I like this answer for avoiding the separate `zlib` import. I do suspect this penalizes code readability, as the direct use of the `zlib` module is front and center, whereas `zlib_codec` in the above is merely part of a chain. Thanks for the great answer!